# Multiple Values in Dropdown List enter into MYSQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a dropdown list that is populated from MYSQL database with the following columns

city | Province | Lats | Longs

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from cities");
echo "<select id='search' name='town'>";
echo "<option>-- Select Town -- </option>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='$row[city];$row[province];$row[lats];$row[longs]'>$row[city] ~ $row[province]</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo "<hr/>";
```

I want to insert the value data into a table each in their own row

How would I do the Insert SQL statement?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "_I want to insert the value data into a table each in their own row_"? Do you mean each option in the dropdown? Do you mean each value in the selected option in the dropdown? It's unclear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Is that option value very much use, as you concatenate the values together? Why wouldn't you just put the city unique id in there, and retrieve it later in whatever you submit the drop-down to? Also, when you say "insert value data into a table", do you mean an SQL table, or a HTML table?

Comment: @droopsnoot The only benefit to this that I can think of is that it prevents an additional database query, and you can just separate the value using `explode()` to access each individual value.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I guess, and I must say I hadn't noticed the `;` separators somehow.

Comment: Well, I would hope the data is being inserted in a relational way, so using the unique id would be the more efficient way overall. User 1 selects city id 24, then 24 is saved for user 1... etc.

Answer (score -1):

I have found that this works

```
$result = $conn->query("select city, province, lats, longs FROM cities");
echo "<html>";
echo "<body>";
echo "<select name='town' id='client'>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

unset($city, $province, $lats, $longs);
$city = $row['city'];
$province = $row['province'];
$lats = $row['lats'];
$longs = $row['longs'];
echo '<option>Select City</option>';
echo '<option value="'.$city.'_'.$province.'_'.$lats.'_'.$longs.'">'.$city.' '.$province.'</option>';
```

In the SQL String I got this to work

```
$town = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'town');
$parts = explode('_', $town);
$city = $parts[0];
$province = $parts[1];
$lats = $parts[2];
$longs = $parts[3];
```